# I deleted my /home/desktop. Now my home directory shows up on the desktop

Tags: directory, home-directory

Of course I could easily restore my backup. But I wonder what mechanism is responsible for this behaviour.
Cheers

`mkdir ~/Schreibtisch`
oder even
`mkdir ~/Desktop`
(each followed logout/login)
did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Recreate the desktop directory, sign out, sign back in 

Comment: But try this first: https://askubuntu.com/a/1168252/1157519

Answer (score 0):

Your ~/Desktop was followed by an i-node, which can't be found after deletion. Recreating a new directory with the same name, but with a new system-appointed i-node will not point your system files to it. Restoring your backup directories won't fix it either. Try to :

a. add a new user
b. copy your local folders into the new users home directory
c. remove your first user account

Good luck :)

Comment: I really wish to see in the end that this was not necessary.